# Mysql query $row returning "bool(true)" instead of results array

Tags: php, mysql

I have done tons of sql queries with left joins over the years but never seen this and I can't find any information on it.

Let start with the query

```
SELECT Services.rn AS srn, Address_Id, Customer_Id, Service_Id, Next_Service, Next_End, Confirmed, Address, First_Name, Last_Name, Company, Service_Type, City
FROM `Services`
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT rn, Address, City_Id FROM `Service_Address`) AS saddresss ON saddresss.rn = Services.Address_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT rn, First_Name, Last_Name, Company FROM `Customer`) AS customer ON customer.rn = Services.Customer_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT rn, Service_Type FROM `Service_Desc`) AS servdesc ON servdesc.rn = Services.Service_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT rn, City FROM `City_List`) AS city ON city.rn = saddresss.City_Id
WHERE `Services`.`Next_Service` BETWEEN " . $daystart . " AND " . $dayend . "
ORDER BY `Services`.`Customer_Id` ASC, `Services`.`Address_Id` ASC, `Services`.`rn` ASC
```

Only thing not included above is $daystart and $dayend variables and they are just unix time stamps.

Normally I then use a while loop to process the results

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    //do something here
}
```

But as I got empty output I decided to debug using var_dump. If you var_dump "$row" you get an array, same if you var_dump "$res->fetch_assoc()". But not this time, if I var_dump the "$res->fetch_assoc()" I get the array, but if I var_dump "$row" I get "bool(true)" for each "row". And if try to echo any of the values in "$row" ($row['City']) I get nothing.

Clearly the results are there as var_dump "$res->fetch_assoc()" shows an array and it has the correct data at that, but I have no idea how I get at it, so I can display it.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I ran the query in phpmyadmin, only substituting $daystart with 1456207200 and $dayend with 1456293599, and it works. Not sure why it wouldn't work in PHP

EDIT 2:

Based on my second comment on DRapp post. I thought maybe the "Services" table structure would be helpful.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Services` (
  `rn` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Address_Id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Service_With` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Service_Id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Service_Desc` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `Initial_Service` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Last_Service` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Next_Service` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Next_End` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Confirmed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `Product_Quantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Product_Rate` double(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `Charge` double(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `Fequency_Id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Route` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Salesman` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Warranty_Expires` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Canceled` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Cancel_Reason` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `Office_Note` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `Customer_Note` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `Technician_Note` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4651 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Ouch lots of sub selects... I would look at inner joins on the ids of the tables...

Comment: Clearly, the `where` clause filters out all the rows.  I would suspect that `Next_Service` is not a unix timestamp.  Sample data and the values of the two variables would clarify what is going on.

Comment: @Codexer I have tried it with inner join and join to see if there would be some difference.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Next_Service is stored as an integer at the very least it would be a 0 in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After get my query down to

```
SELECT *
FROM Services
WHERE Next_Service >=  $daystart AND Next_Service <= $dayend
```

And then starring at it for 30 minutes to see if there was any defect, I  began to suspect my PHP as the culprit. The while loop I provided in my OP is an example of my default while loop for handling query results. The problem is that in this case I had thought to make a quick shortcut to avoid an extra "if" statement. My while loop actually looks something like

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc() && $somevalue != '')
{
    //do something here
}
```

And, if you know anything about syntax, if "$somevalue" was not blank it would set "$row" to "bool(true)".

Just wanted to thank DRapp for his efforts I would accept your answer if I could but as the problem is unrelated to any information provided I am sure it wouldn't fly with SO. This was one of those oh duh moments, I must admit I even hesitated to post as it almost ranks up there with mistakes like forgetting a semicolon (;). But I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaned-up SQL query for you without the proper quotes wrapping, but kept the parameters in place for you.  LEFT-JOIN selects were worthless for you adding unnecessary layers to the query.

I simplified the alias references and hopefully makes more sense to you.  For doing queries, I try to start with the FROM clause and identify all the joins and how each table is directly related in order to get all the fields as needed.  At this point, do not worry about criteria, just HOW they are related.  I also always try to list the FIRST table as the left-side of the ON clause for the join and the right for the one being joined TO.  Also, in the case of the services joined to service address, and then service address to city list, notice how I have them indented...  It makes direct sense on what links to what instead of just being put anywhere and hoping nobody after you needs to figure things out.  Also easier when you have to go back to it at a later time.

```
SELECT 
      S.rn AS srn, 
      S.Address_Id, 
      S.Customer_Id, 
      S.Service_Id, 
      S.Next_Service, 
      Next_End, 
      Confirmed, 
      SvcAdr.Address, 
      Cst.First_Name, 
      Cst.Last_Name, 
      Cst.Company, 
      SD.Service_Type, 
      C.City
   FROM 
      Services AS S
         LEFT JOIN Service_Address AS SvcAdr
            ON S.Address_Id = SvcAdr.rn
            LEFT JOIN City_List AS C
               ON SvcAdr.City_Id = city.rn
         LEFT JOIN Customer  AS Cst
            ON Services.Customer_Id = Cst.rn 
         LEFT JOIN Service_Desc AS SD
            ON S.Service_Id = SD.rn
   WHERE 
      S.Next_Service BETWEEN  $daystart AND  $dayend 
   ORDER BY 
      S.Customer_Id ASC, 
      S.Address_Id ASC, 
      S.rn ASC
```

As for it not working through PHP, is may be coincidence, but also try to always qualify your fields with proper table (or alias) vs guessing.

One final point on the service dates, and it looks like you are using a UNIX-based timestamp.  I would make sure that the beginning is based on 12:00:00 am (midnight) on the start and 11:59:59pm on the last date so you are not missing anything that might be a mid-day of the respective start / end dates.

**FEEDBACK**

Then my suggestion.  Start with ONLY the services query, then add one LEFT-JOIN at a time.  The services, just go with your where date range.  If nothing returns there, you know your toast out the gate.  Also, since you are doing LEFT-JOINs, you may want to apply ex:  COALESCE( SvcAdr.Address, " " ) as Address to prevent nulls coming back.

Start with

```
SELECT 
      S.rn AS srn, 
      S.Address_Id, 
      S.Customer_Id, 
      S.Service_Id, 
      S.Next_Service, 
   FROM 
      Services AS S
   WHERE 
      S.Next_Service BETWEEN  $daystart AND  $dayend
```

Comment: That is basically what the first version of my query looked like. The version in my OP is many iterations later, as I tried to track down the issue. Just to be sure I hadn't over looked something I did give your query a try but still the same issue.

Comment: @Krik, revised answer.  Try starting with minimum to ensure getting an answer back and keep adding until failure occurs.

Comment: Good suggestion, I guess 12 hours makes you forget basic debugging. But it is still failing. I have checked that $daystart and $dayend are set, and that they are integers. Couple odd notes, the var_dump has 4 arrays but also a "NULL" in a spot where a potential fifth array would be. Also ran the exact stripped down query in phpmyadmin and I get 9 results. So something is returning NULL and stopping the query, I am guessing. I double checked that "Next_Service" is set as an integer, and that all values in the "Next_Service" column are numbers.

Comment: Updated my OP see second edit for "Services" table structure.

Comment: @Krik, take it even smaller... For the date-range given from even the phpadmin querying, look at the data within the date range.  Can you narrow it down to only a FEW records, then start 1 column at a time to confirm the array content.  Is it POSSIBLE you have some bad data / corruption / empty fields causing it?  Start few records, then expand 1 or 2 columns at a time until it breaks.  Once all clear, then expand the date range to get more records and possibly find the bad entry (entries) causing problems for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I had to answer my own post as the problem is unrelated to any information I provided.